# Solution to second order PDE $u_{xy}-xu_x+u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given second order partial differential equation $u_{xy}-xu_x+u=0$, where $u=u(x,y)$ find the general solution.

I tried to use $u(x,y)=v(ξ(x,y),η(x,y))$ substitution to get

$$ξ_xξ_yv_{ξξ}+(ξ_xη_y+ξ_yη_x)v_{ξη}+η_xη_yv_{ηη}+ξ_{xy}v_ξ+η_{xy}v_η-x(ξ_xv_ξ+η_xv_η)+v=0,$$

but I couldn't get something useful from this by assuming $ξ_xη_y+ξ_yη_x=0$ or $(ξ_xξ_y=0$ and $η_xη_y=0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_{xy}-xu_x+u=0$$
This elliptic PDE is already on canonical form.

Seach for particular solutions. Method of separation of variables, with $u=f(x)g(y)$
$$f'g'-xf'g+fg=0$$
$\frac{g'}{g}=x-\frac{1}{\frac{f'}{f}}=$(function of $y$)=(function of $x$)=constant=$\lambda$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{g'}{g}=\lambda \\
(x-\lambda)f'-f=0
\end{cases} \qquad\to\qquad 
\begin{cases}
g=c_1e^{\lambda t}\\
f=c_2(x-\lambda)
\end{cases}$$
Particular solution corresponding to a particular value of $\lambda$  where $C_\lambda$ is any constant :

$$u(\lambda ;x,y)=C_{\lambda}(x-\lambda)e^{\lambda t}$$

Solution of the PDE, expressed on the form of series :
$$u(x,y)=\sum_{\lambda} C_{\lambda}(x-\lambda)e^{\lambda t}$$

Solution expressed on integral form :
$$u(x,y)=\int f(\lambda)(x-\lambda)e^{\lambda t}d\lambda$$
where $f(\lambda)$ is any integrable function.

Comment: But it is a particular solution of the form  u=f(x)g(y). How about the general solution? (I am still going to accept this answer)

Comment: The general solution is : $u(x,y)=\int f(\lambda)(x-\lambda)e^{\lambda t}d\lambda$
where $f(\lambda)$ is any integrable function.

Comment: How does it work? I mean you got a particular solution u(λ;x,y) and then what is a reason to integrate it?

Comment: Since the PDE is linear, the sum of particular solutions is also a solution. Summing an infinity of particular solutions is a way to represent a general solution. Similary to infinite series can define special functions. In this case, the generality commes from  the arbitrary function $f(\lambda)$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I am still confused how general solution can be found by assuming u=f(x)g(y) first. I mean, it sounds to me like this is general solution to u=f(x)g(y) according to λ, but not indeed like general general. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is not first assumed that $u=f(x)g(y)$. The touble comes from a bad symbolism. It is assumed that $u_p=f(x)g(x)$ where $u_p(x,y)$ isn't the general solution of the ODE, but is only a particular solution. We found an infinity of different particular solutions (with different $p$ that we latter called $\lambda$). Each one must not be confused with the general solution. When several of these different particular solutions are added, a new function is obtained, which cannot be written on the form $f(x)g(t)$.

Comment: If fact, the whole set of solutions includes all the preceeding particular solutions, plus all linear combinations of them. The less general is when all coefficients are null except one, then giving one of the particular solution. The most general is when all coefficients are not null. But all intermediate cases are possible. Remplacing the discretized version by a function is even more general, since the function can eventually be discretized to go back to the preceeding case.

Comment: Now it makes sense.

Comment: The last question "...since the function can eventually be discretized to go back to the preceeding case" how that could be done (I am trying to fully understand why it is more general)?

Comment: I simply mean that a set of dicretized functions (or piecewise functions) is a sub-set of the set of all functions.